# validation using newdate function

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

tried using the newdate() function to limit the date picker not to select past dates

```
   !function ($) {

     var DateRangePicker = function (element, options, cb) {
     var hasOptions = typeof options == 'object';
     var localeObject;

    //option defaults

    this.startDate = moment().startOf('day');
    this.endDate = moment().startOf('day');
    this.minDate =  new Date();
    this.maxDate = false;
    this.dateLimit = false;
```

Comment: I would guess that it expects a moment object? So just try `moment()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try writing only `Date()` instead of `new Date()`

Hope it might help.